# Flat-file PHP issue tracker

Tags: open-source, php, self-hosted, issue-tracker

I need a self-hosted issue tracker that

- is written in PHP,
- doesn’t require a database, and
- is free/libre/open source.

#### Required features

- An issue can have a category ("bug", "feature request", "support") and a status ("closed", "open", "on hold").
- An issue can be commented.
- Issues and comments can have image attachments.
- Email notifications for new issues and new comments.
- The list of issues can be filtered by category and status.

#### Nice-to-have features

- When referencing issues/comments internally, the links should be relative (or there should be a config option to change the hostname) so that switching domains is hassle-free.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Traq](https://github.com/nirix/traq). It runs with the file based "database" Sqlite (look at the travis configurations).

It has a nice user interface and all the features you are looking for.